# System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: WAOSA_URL: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) - video files

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Essentially, this is an app that was created by a development team and I am just trying to get the app to work on the newest Android SDK's (targeting 30). At this point, I am still very new to Android Studio and mobile development so I am only trying to get the app back to working with all features even if the API's are deprecated and will need to be upgraded soon. Once it is up and running, I can work on the deprecated aspects. I would also be okay with lowering the targeted SDK *for now* to something like 28 or 29.

The errors are thrown when I play back a video on the app. The videos are there and the thumbnails show up without issue, but they don't play back. The app shows `"something error"` on the player while trying to play it. The app doesn't crash or leave the screen. It just continually tries to play the video until the user exits the page.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Let me know if I am missing any code that I should have added to the post.

**Here's the errors:**

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: WAOSA_URL: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1182)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1160)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1076)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1097)
        at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.AndroidMediaPlayer.setDataSource(AndroidMediaPlayer.java:94)
        at tcking.github.com.giraffeplayer2.GiraffePlayer.init(GiraffePlayer.java:421)
        at tcking.github.com.giraffeplayer2.GiraffePlayer.access$600(GiraffePlayer.java:54)
        at tcking.github.com.giraffeplayer2.GiraffePlayer$1.handleMessage(GiraffePlayer.java:222)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open WAOSA_URL
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: WAOSA_URL
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1673)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1503)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1420)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1101)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1073)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1097)
        at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.AndroidMediaPlayer.setDataSource(AndroidMediaPlayer.java:94)
        at tcking.github.com.giraffeplayer2.GiraffePlayer.init(GiraffePlayer.java:421)
        at tcking.github.com.giraffeplayer2.GiraffePlayer.access$600(GiraffePlayer.java:54)
        at tcking.github.com.giraffeplayer2.GiraffePlayer$1.handleMessage(GiraffePlayer.java:222)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
    cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
W/MediaPlayer: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
W/MediaPlayer: See the documentation of setAudioStreamType() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
    Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
    See the documentation of setAudioStreamType() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
```

**Build.gradle (app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() 
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
    }
}
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "//removed for privacy"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 3
        versionName '3.1'
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    ndkVersion '20.0.5594570'
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.4.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:compose-theme-adapter:1.0.0-beta08'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-rc01'

    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:20030203.000550'
    implementation group: 'com.bikomobile', name: 'multipart', version: '1.3.4'

    // The GoCoder SDK library dependency declaration
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.6@aar'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.reginald:editspinner:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.14'
    implementation 'com.github.tcking:viewquery:1.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:20.1.0'

    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.10'
    implementation 'com.github.dynckathline:danmaku:1.0'

    implementation files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')

    implementation 'com.github.tcking:giraffeplayer2:0.1.25'

    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.3.0'

    implementation group: 'com.github.tcking', name: 'ijkplayer-x86_64', version: '0.8.8'

    api 'com.github.tcking:giraffeplayer2:0.1.25'
    api 'com.github.tcking:giraffeplayer2:0.1.25-lazyLoad'
    api 'com.github.tcking:giraffeplayer2:0.1.25-full'

    api 'com.github.tcking:ijkplayer-arm64:0.8.8-full' //support arm64
    api 'com.github.tcking:ijkplayer-armv5:0.8.8-full' //support armv5
    api 'com.github.tcking:ijkplayer-x86:0.8.8-full' //support x86
    api 'com.github.tcking:ijkplayer-x86_64:0.8.8-full' //support x86_64

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Class ActivityStreamVideo:**

```
package com.ccgo.utility;

/*
This class is used to stream online video
 */
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import com.ccgo.R;
import com.ccgo.utility.AppConstant;
import com.ccgo.utility.Utility;

public class ActivityStreamVideo extends Activity {

    // Declare variables
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;
    private String VIDEO_ID="";
    // Insert your Video URL
    String VideoURL = "";
    private PreferenceManager pref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the layout from video_main.xml

        pref                        =           new PreferenceManager(this);
        if(pref.getThemeId()== AppConstant.THEME_GREEN)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_stream_video);
        }
        else
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_stream_video_red);
        }

        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
        videoview = findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask

        //Getting Intent Data
        getIntentData();

        // Create a progressbar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityStreamVideo.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        pDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();

        try
        {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    ActivityStreamVideo.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse("//removed for privacy");

            Log.d("UPLOAD",video.toString());
            if(!video.toString().equals("") || video!=null) {
                videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
                videoview.setVideoURI(video);
            }
            else
            {
                Utility.displayToast(ActivityStreamVideo.this,getString(R.string.video_not_found));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
        {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();
            }
        });
    
    }

    //Method to get intent data
    private void getIntentData()
    {
        try
        {
            VIDEO_ID        =       getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_ID");
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ccgo">

    <!--<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEFAULT_SCOPED_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <!--<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />-->
    <!--<permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />-->
    <!--<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />-->

    <!--<uses-feature-->
    <!--android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"-->
    <!--android:required="false" />-->

    <application

        android:name=".utility.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">-->

        <activity
            android:name=".login.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.StatusBar.Light"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".login.activity.ActivityForgotPassword"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.StatusBar.Light"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".coach.activity.ActivityRecordVideo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_challenge"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".company_admin.activity.ActivityViewLicenseInformation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_challenge"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".company_admin.activity.ActivityManageNotification"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_challenge"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityManageTheme"
            android:label="@string/manage_theme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".coach.activity.ActivityCreateChallengeSubmission"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_challenge"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".company_admin.activity.ActivityAddVote"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_challenge"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".coach.activity.ActivityCreateChallenge"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_challenge"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".coach.activity.ActivityPreviewVideo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_challenge"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".coach.activity.ActivityPreviewDescription"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_challenge"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".login.activity.ActivityLogin"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.StatusBar.Light"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <!--dynamicLink intent filter starts-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="//removed for privacy"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="//removed for privacy"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <!--dynamicLink intent filter ends-->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".company_admin.activity.ActivityOngoingChallengesDetail"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.StatusBar.Light"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".company_admin.activity.ActivityEditChallenge"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.StatusBar.Light"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".company_admin.activity.ActivityResponseDetail"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.StatusBar.Light"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".company_admin.activity.ActivityViewLeaderBoard"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".coach.activity.ActivityViewTeamLeaderBoardCaoch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".company_admin.activity.ActivityManageLibraryDetail"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".utility.ConnectivityReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".SampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sample"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- Firebase Notifications -->

        <!--  <service android:name=".notification.MyFireBaseIntanceIDService">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
             </intent-filter>
         </service> -->

         <service android:name=".notification.MyFireBaseMessagingService">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
             </intent-filter>
         </service>

         <activity
             android:name=".company_admin.activity.ViewTeamActivity"
             android:label="Select Team"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme.StatusBar.Light" />

         <provider
             android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
             android:authorities="com.ccgo.provider"
             android:exported="false"
             android:grantUriPermissions="true">
             <meta-data
                 android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                 android:resource="@xml/external_files" />
         </provider>

         <activity android:name=".company_admin.activity.ActivityManageLibraryResponse" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
     </application>

 </manifest>
```

These are the errors if I try to play a video back in a different area of the app:

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open WAOSA_URL
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: WAOSA_URL
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1673)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1503)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1420)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1101)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1073)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1097)
        at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:412)
        at android.widget.VideoView.access$2200(VideoView.java:83)
        at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:694)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface(SurfaceView.java:758)
        at android.view.SurfaceView$2.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:155)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1088)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2745)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues you are facing could be a result of your app having to comply with new file access restrictions after you upgraded the gradle file to `targetSdkVersion` of 30.

While Google's documentation isn't great, this was the best information I've been able to find to learn more about this:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955 (make sure to expand the sections at the bottom of this page)

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/mwaqn1/scoped_storage_recap/ (this one focuses more on Scoped Storage, but is still helpful)